# FileZilla server returns folder name in NLST response

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, filezilla, ftpwebrequest

I have made some code that connects to an FTP server.

My problem is that I against some servers get both folder and filename, e.g. `myfolder\myfile.txt`, and others just get `myfile.txt`.

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/myfolder"); 
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
var ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
var ftpResponeStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
var ftpStreamReader = new StreamReader(ftpResponeStream);

string line;
while ((line = ftpStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

I would prefer that I just get `myfile.txt` because that is how the real code should run, but I don't know, if this is a FileZilla setting or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL for the `ListDirectory` method should end with a slash, in general.

Without a slash, results tend to be uncertain, largely depending on the FTP server implementation.

```
(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/myfolder/");
```

---

With a URL like `ftp://ftp.example.com/parent/folder`, without the slash, the `FtpWebRequest` does:

```
CWD /parent
NLST folder
```

In this case, some FTP servers include the `folder` in the listing, while some do not.

While with a slash, the `FtpWebRequest` does:

```
CWD /parent/folder
NLST
```

In this case, the listing includes bare filenames.

Comment: The solution works for me, and both FTP servers now consistently gives me a result without foldernames.